# Network bandwidth limitation in KVM

Tags: networking, server, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, bandwidth

I'm having difficulties finding out how to limit network bandwidth for my VM. The results I found searching the web that libvirt already includes this function, but I can't find it anywhere. Using the `virsh edit` command to edit the VM's settings, I still couldn't find any parameters related to bandwidth control. I also tried adding the mentioned function in the document, but results in a heap of errors. I would like to know if it's possible to add this function to my VM.
Document: http://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementQoS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add these parameters by hand. When you open the xml file of your virtual machine, find the block with `interface type` tag. Try to add the following

```
<bandwidth>
  <inbound average='xxx' peak='xxx' burst='xxxx'/>
  <outbound average='xxx' peak='xxx'/>
</bandwidth>
```

Where **xxx** is desired speed in kbps (kilobits per second). I think you have a little wrong url, here is the [proper](http://libvirt.org/formatnetwork.html#elementQoS) one

Comment: I see where the mistake was now. Works like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: The documentation seems to specify kilobytes, and not kilobits.